# Flutter Graddle Version Issue

Tags: flutter

This is the error I am getting

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/beast/AndroidStudioProjects/flash-chat-flutter/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using Gradle tool version 4.0.0? (inside your root build.gradle file). Modify your distributionURL to 6.1.1 and that's it

Comment: Yes that was the error

Answer (score -1):

Open *Android Studio*: settings and open Gradle, check the version of it.

1. Try clicking use default Gradle wrapper and run project it will Download updated Gradle.
2. You can download Gradle dependency.

Like this:

```
buildscript {
      ...
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome,if it worked tag is it as correct answer :)